# Read .dat file in binary mode in PowerShell to avoid conversion of special characters into garbage character

Tags: powershell, filereader

I want to read a .dat file as binary stream in powershell. As I am new to Powershell, not able to figure out how it can be done. 
After file being read as a binary stream and would like to replace the binary CRLF characters with LF..

Comment: `Get-Content -Encoding Byte`? What do you want to do with the data after it was read (other than replacing line breaks)?

Comment: I just want to replace line breaks and write data into a new file

Comment: ```Set-Content .\newfile.dat -Value ((Get-Content $file) -join "`n")```

Comment: thanks Mathias. But data file have characters as below : These characters are not getting converted properly. test‡test → testx82test    test,test → testx82test

Comment: Specify the proper encoding.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen: Note that you also need `-NoNewline` (and a manually appended LF), otherwise `Set-Content` will append a trailing CRLF (on Windows).

Comment: @TAdhav: Note that Windows PowerShell defaults to "ANSI" encoding for both `Get-Content` and `Set-Content`. If your input file is UTF-8-encoded but has _no BOM_, for instance, it will be misinterpreted; use `-Encoding` to control the character encoding on both reading and writing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use .Net `$bytes = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("<YOUR FILE>")` or Powershell `$bytes = Get-Content -Path "<YOUR FILE>" -Encoding Byte -Raw` to read the binary data as byte array (`System.Byte[]`).

If you convert that to ASCII string with `$text = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString($bytes)` you should be able to replace the CRLF to LF.

Something like this:

```
# read the binary data as byte array
$bytes = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("<YOUR FILE>")
# convert to ASCII string
$text = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString($bytes)

# replace the CRLF to LF
$text = $text -replace "`r`n", "`n"

# convert back to byte array
$bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($text)
```

Comment: this data file have charcters as below : These characters are not getting converted properly. test‡test → test????test
test,test → test???test

Comment: The read-as-bytes techniques are useful, but only needed if you're dealing with a (partly) binary file or if you have no idea what (single-byte) character encoding the input file uses.
If you do know the character encoding, just use `Get/Set-Content -Encoding`; if it's an exotic encoding that PowerShell doesn't expose but .NET does, use the `[System.IO.File]` text-file method overloads that accept an encoding object.